# Finding longest path in a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary which contains a start node, end node and distance between them. For eg:

```
{'A': {('B', 1.0), ('C', 5.0)}, 'B': {('D', 2.0), ('E', 4.0), ('A', 1.0)}, 'C': {('A', 5.0), ('E', 3.0), ('D', 2.0)}, 'D': {('E', 1.0), ('C', 2.0), ('B', 2.0)}, 'E': {('D', 1.0), ('B', 4.0), ('C', 3.0)}}
```

distance between A and B is 1.0, A and C is 5.0, B and D is 2.0...I need to find the maximum distance and display the value i.e in this case A:C which is 5.0 using basic for loop without using builtin functions like .iterations, .keys,yield,sort  and so on but can use split. Can someone guide me how to do this? I am new to python.

Comment: To get this clear: You are not looking for the [longest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path), but simply for the longest distance between any two connected nodes in the graph?

Comment: Have you thought about using an adjacency list or an adjacency matrix?.  Either would be easier to traverse if you're trying to represent a graph.

Comment: Why can't you use `.keys()`? And why the allowance for `split()`, seeing as all strings have length 1 anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
print max((l[1], l[0], k) for k in d for l in d[k])
# (5.0, 'C', 'A')
```

Comment: @fourtheye How do i modify the code to return all the nodes between the two nodes of shortest path. For ex: to travel from A to C, i should go from A->B->D->C. So i need an output like (5.0,['A','B','D','C']).